# Upload multiple thumbnail images to Google Drive API file?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Using Google Drive API's files.patch, is it possible to provide multiple thumbnail images?  Like, a thumbnail for each page of a custom document?  The PDF Drive popup preview does this, but how can I?

This is an example of patching the metadata (with javascript); notice that it only allows one thumbnail as documented.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.patch(
{
        'fileId': file_id,
        'thumbnail':
        {
            'image': thumb_base64urlsafe_data,
            'mimeType': thumb_mimetype
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can submit a single thumbnail for a resource.

Our previewer does its own custom rendering of PDF's to be able to display it.